# Comma is illegal outside of backquotes?

Tags: list, syntax, lisp, common-lisp, backquote

I am writing a function that is supposed to take in two values. The first value is supposed to create a list up to five numbers, based on the value entered. The second value is supposed to take the list and rotate it `n` times, based on the number entered.

Example of program interaction.

`> (my_rotate_n 1,2)`

`> (3 4 5 1 2)`

This is the function I currently have.

```
(defun my_rotate_n (y) (x)
    (append (loop for i from (+ 1 y) to (+ 4 y) collect i)
    (> x 0) (my_rotate_n (rotate-right y)(- x 1)))(list y))
```

When I test the function for an output I get the error: `comma is illegal outside of backquotes` Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't use commas to separate arguments. Use a space. Looking at that function, you don't seem to be quite familiar with Lisp syntax. You should read some Lisp book (try the [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) for example).

Answer (score 4):

[Comma](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dg.htm):

> The comma is part of the backquote syntax; see [Section 2.4.6
>    (Backquote)](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_df.htm).
>    Comma is invalid if used other than inside the body of a backquote expression as described above.

To separate tokens, use [Whitespace Characters](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_adg.htm).

IOW, instead of `(my_rotate_n 1,2)` you should write `(my_rotate_n 1 2)`.

(This will not make your `my_rotate_n` work, of course, just avoid that particular error. You should invest some of your time in studying Lisp syntax.)